# CustomView don't show in design mode

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, layout-inflater, custom-view

I have a `CustomView` extend from `RelativeLayout`.
I Use this `CustomView` in layout file but *Android Studio* in design mode not showing the `CustomView`. what is problem?

koala_appbar.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    tools:context=".activity.basic.BaseActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/appbar_imgLogo"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/appBar_iconWidth"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/appBar_iconHeight"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/appBar_iconTopMargin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/appBar_iconLeftMargin"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/appbar_height"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layoutDirection="ltr"
        >

        <koala.android.customer.views.widget.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/appBar_txtTitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center|right"
            android:text="@string/app_name_persian"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="@dimen/TextSize_large"
            app:tvCustomFont="@string/baseFont"
            />

        <koala.android.customer.views.widget.CustomImageView
            android:id="@+id/appBar_imgBack"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/appbar_height"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_right"
            app:ivDrawableTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:padding="@dimen/appBar_backPadding"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

KoalaAppBar.java:

```
public class KoalaAppBar extends RelativeLayout {


    private static final String DEFAULT_TITLE = "default";

    private static final int DEFAULT_TITLE_COLOR = ResourcesCompat.getColor(AppController.getContext().getResources(), R.color.colorPrimary , null);

    private static final float DEFAULT_TITLE_FONT_SIZE = AppController.getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.TextSize_small);


    protected CustomTextView txtTitle;

    protected CustomImageView imgBack;

    protected ImageView imgLogo;



    public KoalaAppBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context , null);
    }

    public KoalaAppBar(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context , attrs);
    }

    public KoalaAppBar(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context , attrs);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public KoalaAppBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

        if(context != null){
            findViews(context);
        }

        if(attrs != null){
            initAttribute(context,attrs);
        }
    }

    private void initAttribute(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.KoalaAppBar);

        String title = a.getString(R.styleable.KoalaAppBar_appTitle);

        if(title == null || title.isEmpty()){
            title = DEFAULT_TITLE;
        }

        int titleColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.KoalaAppBar_appTitleColor, DEFAULT_TITLE_COLOR);

        float fontSize = a.getDimension(R.styleable.KoalaAppBar_appTitleFontSize, DEFAULT_TITLE_FONT_SIZE);

        boolean logoVisibility = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.KoalaAppBar_appLogoVisibility , true);


        initTitle(title , titleColor , fontSize);

        initLogo(logoVisibility);

        a.recycle();
    }

    private void initLogo(boolean logoVisibility) {
        if(logoVisibility){
            this.imgLogo.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }else{
            this.imgLogo.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
    }

    private void initTitle(String title, int titleColor, float fontSize) {
        this.txtTitle.setText(title);
        this.txtTitle.setTextColor(titleColor);
        this.txtTitle.setTextSize(fontSize);
    }

    private void findViews(Context context) {
        View rootView =
                LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                        R.layout.koala_appbar,
                        this,
                        true
                );


        this.txtTitle   = rootView.findViewById(R.id.appBar_txtTitle);

        this.imgBack    = rootView.findViewById(R.id.appBar_imgBack);

        this.imgLogo = rootView.findViewById(R.id.appbar_imgLogo);
    }


}
```

Comment: try to `Build > Rebuild Project`

Comment: Any errors or screenshots?

Comment: @AadityaBrahmbhatt  first solution you can find is build -> rebuild :))

Comment: Post code of you `CustomView` then.

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท work good on android device but not showing on design mode

Comment: That's why I said you should add screenshot of the Android preview. Are you using v28.0.0-rc02 or alpha version of support Library? It's hard to tell what is the issue without any errors or codes.

Comment: @MortezaJalambadani  help us to help you and BTW have a look how to create [mcve]

Comment: If you have custom view which is created dynamically during application work it doesn't appear in design mode.

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท support library is v7:27.1.1

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท question edit.

Comment: @DennyDog question edit.

Comment: @AadityaBrahmbhatt question edit.

Comment: DannyDog is right. That's a dynamic view which creates after compiling.

Comment: @MortezaJalambadani before we do anything, have you tried changing your devices (Nexus 5, 4, Pixel etc) and API version in editor. (I just checked that my custom view wasn't showing until I played a little with the settings).    If it was completely custom view then we could have assumed that there might be problem in `onDraw()` but you haven't override it so that shouldn't be the problem.